# Covering a Shofar to prevent the spread of Coronavirus

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar, elul, covid19-pandemic

Two nights ago, [as part of his weekly livestream COVID update](https://youtu.be/jHkL1y2ZJZ4?t=1786), Rabbi Dr. Glatt quoted Rav Mordechai Willig (he quoted "Poskim" but the implication was that it was Rav Mordechai Willig. Even if it was someone else, the question would be unaffected) that one should put a mask over the wide end of the Shofar while blowing to prevent spreading COVID. The Rabbi of the Shul I Davened at yesterday (a close Talmid of Rav Mordechai Willig) was convinced that Rav Mordechai Willig was either misquoted or would retract this soon.

His reasoning was that he feels putting a mask changes the tone and would render the blowing Passul.

Does anyone know whether this is true? The Rabbi tried demonstrating but it was hard to tell (it certainly muffles the sound but it was unclear if the tone was changed as well) because its so easy to change the tone anyway. You move it the tiniest bit and the tone is different.

Has anyone heard anything else about this Shaila? Does anyone have any Maareh Mekomos that they can think of that may be relevant? Have any other well known Rabbanim weighed in on this?

Comment: crossposted: https://judaism.codidact.com/q/277287

Comment: Probably depends on the mask and shofar, no? Why would anyone make a general statement about this?

Comment: Is he discussing Rosh Hashana when it is D'Oraasoh or Chodosh Elul when it is a minhag?

Comment: @Schmerel Rosh Hashana

Comment: @msh210 Yeah. I didn't get an answer there (I did get useful comments) and in meta they told me to post here as well.

Comment: not that it should matter if it's pasul, but tekias shofar is derabanan this year as the first day is on Shabbos